# How to deal with INF and NAN values in Tensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement ["Generating Sequences With Recurrent Neural Networks"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.0850.pdf) by Alex Graves.

I've implemented the loss function as I understood from the paper but while training my tensors have inf or nan values. How should be they dealt with?

This is my first attempt at any paper implementation. Please do let me know if I am doing something wrong.

My Model :

```
class GenerationModel(Model) :
    def __init__ (self, hidden_size = 256, n_layers=3, n_gaussians=10, dropout=0):
        super(GenerationModel, self).__init__()
        
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.n_layers= n_layers
        self.n_gaussians = n_gaussians
        self.dropout = dropout
        # self.input_ = Input(batch_shape=(50, 300, 3))
        self.lstm = LSTM(self.hidden_size, batch_input_shape=(50, 300, 3), return_sequences=True, dtype='float32')
        self.e_h = Dense(1, activation='relu')
        self.pi_h = Dense(self.n_gaussians, input_shape=(self.hidden_size,), activation='softmax')
        self.mu1_h = Dense(self.n_gaussians, input_shape=(self.hidden_size, ), activation='relu')
        self.mu2_h = Dense(self.n_gaussians, input_shape=(self.hidden_size, ), activation='relu')
        self.sig1_h = Dense(self.n_gaussians, input_shape=(self.hidden_size, ), activation='relu')
        self.sig2_h = Dense(self.n_gaussians, input_shape=(self.hidden_size, ), activation='relu')
        self.rho_h = Dense(self.n_gaussians, input_shape=(self.hidden_size,), activation = 'tanh')
        self.concat = Concatenate()

    def call(self, inputs, training) :
        x = self.lstm(inputs)

        e_t = Lambda(tf.sigmoid)(-self.e_h(x))

        pi_t = self.pi_h(x)

        # print(pi_t.shape)

        mu1_t = self.mu1_h(x)
        mu2_t = self.mu2_h(x)

        sig1_t = self.sig1_h(x)
        sig2_t = self.sig2_h(x)


        sig1_t = Lambda(tf.math.exp)(sig1_t)
        sig2_t = Lambda(tf.math.exp)(sig2_t)

        rho_t = self.rho_h(x)

        return self.concat([e_t, pi_t, mu1_t, mu2_t, sig1_t, sig2_t, rho_t])
```

Here is my loss function :

```
def loss(y_true, pred) :
    
    e, pi, mu1, mu2, sig1, sig2, rho = tf.split(pred, axis=2, num_or_size_splits=[1, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10])

    # n_mixtures = pi.shape[1]
    n_mixtures = 10
    
    # 1st term
    x1 = tf.expand_dims(y_true[:,:, 0], axis = 2)
    x1_norm = ((x1- mu1) ** 2) / (sig1 ** 2)

    # 2nd term
    x2 = tf.expand_dims(y_true[:,:, 1], axis = 2)
    x2_norm = ((x1- mu1) ** 2) / (sig1 ** 2)

    # 3rd term
    coxnorm = 2 * rho * (x1 - mu1) * (x2 - mu2) / (sig1 * sig2) 
    Z = tf.add(x1_norm, tf.subtract(x2_norm, coxnorm))
    N = tf.divide(tf.exp(-Z / (2 * (1 - (rho**2)))), (2 * pi * sig1 * sig2 * tf.sqrt(1 - (rho**2))))

    Pr = tf.multiply(pi, N)

    Pr = tf.math.reduce_sum(Pr, axis=2)

    loss1 = - tf.math.log(Pr + eps)

    bernouilli = tf.zeros(tf.squeeze(e).shape)

    y_true_e = tf.expand_dims(y_true[:, :, 2], axis=2)
    bernouilli = tf.add(y_true_e * e , tf.multiply((1 - y_true_e), (1 - e)))

    loss2 = -tf.math.log(bernouilli + eps)

    loss =  tf.add(tf.expand_dims(loss1, axis = 2), loss2)


    loss = tf.reduce_sum(loss, axis=0)
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(loss)

    if loss > 20000 or loss < -20000  or tf.math.is_nan(loss) or tf.math.is_inf(loss):
        print('loss : ', loss)
        print('x1_norm : ', x1_norm)
        print('x2_norm : ', x2_norm)
        print('coxnorm : ', coxnorm)
        print('Z : ', Z)
        print('N : ', N)
        print('Pr1 : ', Pr)
        print('Pr : ', Pr)
        print('loss1 : ', loss1)
        print('bernouilli2 : ', bernouilli)
        print('loss2 : ', loss2)

    else :
        return  loss
```

The 'N' tensor is first to contain inf and nan values.

Here's a print where the inf drops in :

```
loss_val :  tf.Tensor(14799.755, shape=(), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(14799.755, shape=(), dtype=float32)
Epoch :  0  - step  0 / 364  - loss  tf.Tensor(14799.755, shape=(), dtype=float32)  in  2.1774332523345947
loss :  tf.Tensor(nan, shape=(), dtype=float32)
x1_norm :  tf.Tensor(
[[[1.44000006e+00 1.44000006e+00 6.88383639e-01 ... 9.60435748e-01
   1.44000006e+00 1.44000006e+00]
  [1.60000011e-01 1.60000011e-01 1.83394421e-02 ... 5.00380024e-02
   1.60000011e-01 1.60000011e-01]
  [2.22228542e-02 0.00000000e+00 2.47162607e-05 ... 1.82457606e-03
   0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
  ...
  [1.49235502e-01 6.69232290e-03 9.45161446e-05 ... 6.36336626e-04
   1.91709280e-01 2.69679427e-02]
  [1.31852710e+00 2.23670490e-02 1.36851726e-04 ... 1.02013210e-03
   5.61592638e-01 2.85041099e-03]
  [3.98514414e+00 1.95004493e-02 7.00252622e-06 ... 2.28732879e-05
   3.28314155e-01 6.70733273e-01]]

 [[4.89999980e-01 4.89999980e-01 3.34467798e-01 ... 3.88765007e-01
   4.89999980e-01 4.89999980e-01]
  [7.17621002e+01 4.73953743e+01 1.83839531e+01 ... 2.78771858e+01
   7.26256790e+01 7.39600067e+01]
  [9.53735113e-02 8.18452705e-03 2.15586890e-02 ... 4.29287106e-02
   1.29203767e-01 3.66849564e-02]
  ...
  [2.44997218e-01 3.76363573e-06 6.44127722e-05 ... 3.20460880e-04
   2.46068339e-05 2.42545456e-01]
  [1.95206832e-02 1.62190932e-04 1.02208942e-04 ... 4.52216365e-04
   2.37486064e-02 1.05161764e-01]
  [2.75051713e-01 6.82370504e-03 1.16447191e-04 ... 8.43512767e-04
   1.87145755e-01 1.57047790e-02]]

 [[2.97182985e-02 6.41410872e-02 4.04765569e-02 ... 4.00000028e-02
   4.41798046e-02 3.44162062e-02]
  [2.66512185e-01 4.00269866e-01 3.60000014e-01 ... 3.60000014e-01
   3.18260938e-01 2.95530528e-01]
  [1.33533823e+00 1.68999982e+00 1.68999982e+00 ... 1.68999982e+00
   1.25017488e+00 1.38170397e+00]
  ...
  [1.19940203e-03 3.12449574e-03 5.84254594e-05 ... 5.40562265e-04
   1.07474685e-01 4.59237099e-02]
  [3.23814213e-01 2.18871923e-04 4.56716880e-05 ... 3.02338885e-04
   1.08762446e-03 1.71984255e-01]
  [4.06847805e-01 2.73443962e-04 4.21538134e-05 ... 2.89804128e-04
   1.50313252e-04 1.76406831e-01]]

 ...

 [[1.57077807e-06 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 ... 1.17938570e-03
   0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
  [4.06996869e-02 5.77863939e-02 8.08103301e-04 ... 1.38999822e-04
   9.00000036e-02 9.00000036e-02]
  [7.31500387e-02 8.53758827e-02 3.12256670e-05 ... 9.37523029e-04
   3.60000014e-01 3.60000014e-01]
  ...
  [3.28450575e-02 3.56871122e-03 6.23924279e-05 ... 6.79039047e-04
   1.32847846e-01 1.83881111e-02]
  [2.03377917e-01 1.33650401e-05 3.84667765e-05 ... 3.79802164e-04
   1.34165548e-02 1.00817263e-01]
  [9.35007706e-02 3.05744034e-04 4.20509095e-05 ... 4.19727759e-04
   3.15307714e-02 7.74485022e-02]]

 [[1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 7.97997355e-01 ... 9.21857297e-01
   1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]
  [1.68999982e+00 1.68999982e+00 5.84876537e-01 ... 1.01203430e+00
   1.68999982e+00 1.68999982e+00]
  [1.21000004e+00 1.21000004e+00 8.56924504e-02 ... 3.06337684e-01
   1.21000004e+00 1.21000004e+00]
  ...
  [3.72084641e+00 4.87292632e-02 1.22573969e-04 ... 1.23439042e-03
   1.39445615e+00 1.11317866e-01]
  [6.61150169e+00 8.67089257e-02 1.72304819e-04 ... 1.56479154e-03
   2.22197962e+00 2.45437562e-01]
  [5.26128483e+00 8.61922130e-02 1.84978067e-04 ... 1.51262875e-03
   2.11326718e+00 1.91202462e-01]]

 [[8.01521093e-02 1.03490219e-01 2.10033879e-02 ... 2.08099615e-02
   1.02674112e-01 1.60000011e-01]
  [4.63423669e-01 2.46172473e-01 9.89436265e-03 ... 2.09036488e-02
   5.80585420e-01 8.09999943e-01]
  [1.38543904e-01 1.56719349e-02 5.86461043e-04 ... 3.39257857e-03
   1.39181942e-01 4.83793646e-01]
  ...
  [4.58064461e+00 7.45822117e-02 2.22630406e-04 ... 1.49358565e-03
   1.76204622e+00 1.31853864e-01]
  [5.92713165e+00 1.01549268e-01 2.64897913e-04 ... 1.74445310e-03
   2.32883406e+00 2.15858519e-01]
  [6.92767382e+00 1.24643743e-01 2.99515697e-04 ... 1.94842287e-03
   2.82346582e+00 2.90022254e-01]]], shape=(50, 300, 10), dtype=float32)
x2_norm :  tf.Tensor(
[[[1.44000006e+00 1.44000006e+00 6.88383639e-01 ... 9.60435748e-01
   1.44000006e+00 1.44000006e+00]
  [1.60000011e-01 1.60000011e-01 1.83394421e-02 ... 5.00380024e-02
   1.60000011e-01 1.60000011e-01]
  [2.22228542e-02 0.00000000e+00 2.47162607e-05 ... 1.82457606e-03
   0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
  ...
  [1.49235502e-01 6.69232290e-03 9.45161446e-05 ... 6.36336626e-04
   1.91709280e-01 2.69679427e-02]
  [1.31852710e+00 2.23670490e-02 1.36851726e-04 ... 1.02013210e-03
   5.61592638e-01 2.85041099e-03]
  [3.98514414e+00 1.95004493e-02 7.00252622e-06 ... 2.28732879e-05
   3.28314155e-01 6.70733273e-01]]

 [[4.89999980e-01 4.89999980e-01 3.34467798e-01 ... 3.88765007e-01
   4.89999980e-01 4.89999980e-01]
  [7.17621002e+01 4.73953743e+01 1.83839531e+01 ... 2.78771858e+01
   7.26256790e+01 7.39600067e+01]
  [9.53735113e-02 8.18452705e-03 2.15586890e-02 ... 4.29287106e-02
   1.29203767e-01 3.66849564e-02]
  ...
  [2.44997218e-01 3.76363573e-06 6.44127722e-05 ... 3.20460880e-04
   2.46068339e-05 2.42545456e-01]
  [1.95206832e-02 1.62190932e-04 1.02208942e-04 ... 4.52216365e-04
   2.37486064e-02 1.05161764e-01]
  [2.75051713e-01 6.82370504e-03 1.16447191e-04 ... 8.43512767e-04
   1.87145755e-01 1.57047790e-02]]

 [[2.97182985e-02 6.41410872e-02 4.04765569e-02 ... 4.00000028e-02
   4.41798046e-02 3.44162062e-02]
  [2.66512185e-01 4.00269866e-01 3.60000014e-01 ... 3.60000014e-01
   3.18260938e-01 2.95530528e-01]
  [1.33533823e+00 1.68999982e+00 1.68999982e+00 ... 1.68999982e+00
   1.25017488e+00 1.38170397e+00]
  ...
  [1.19940203e-03 3.12449574e-03 5.84254594e-05 ... 5.40562265e-04
   1.07474685e-01 4.59237099e-02]
  [3.23814213e-01 2.18871923e-04 4.56716880e-05 ... 3.02338885e-04
   1.08762446e-03 1.71984255e-01]
  [4.06847805e-01 2.73443962e-04 4.21538134e-05 ... 2.89804128e-04
   1.50313252e-04 1.76406831e-01]]

 ...

 [[1.57077807e-06 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 ... 1.17938570e-03
   0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
  [4.06996869e-02 5.77863939e-02 8.08103301e-04 ... 1.38999822e-04
   9.00000036e-02 9.00000036e-02]
  [7.31500387e-02 8.53758827e-02 3.12256670e-05 ... 9.37523029e-04
   3.60000014e-01 3.60000014e-01]
  ...
  [3.28450575e-02 3.56871122e-03 6.23924279e-05 ... 6.79039047e-04
   1.32847846e-01 1.83881111e-02]
  [2.03377917e-01 1.33650401e-05 3.84667765e-05 ... 3.79802164e-04
   1.34165548e-02 1.00817263e-01]
  [9.35007706e-02 3.05744034e-04 4.20509095e-05 ... 4.19727759e-04
   3.15307714e-02 7.74485022e-02]]

 [[1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00 7.97997355e-01 ... 9.21857297e-01
   1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]
  [1.68999982e+00 1.68999982e+00 5.84876537e-01 ... 1.01203430e+00
   1.68999982e+00 1.68999982e+00]
  [1.21000004e+00 1.21000004e+00 8.56924504e-02 ... 3.06337684e-01
   1.21000004e+00 1.21000004e+00]
  ...
  [3.72084641e+00 4.87292632e-02 1.22573969e-04 ... 1.23439042e-03
   1.39445615e+00 1.11317866e-01]
  [6.61150169e+00 8.67089257e-02 1.72304819e-04 ... 1.56479154e-03
   2.22197962e+00 2.45437562e-01]
  [5.26128483e+00 8.61922130e-02 1.84978067e-04 ... 1.51262875e-03
   2.11326718e+00 1.91202462e-01]]

 [[8.01521093e-02 1.03490219e-01 2.10033879e-02 ... 2.08099615e-02
   1.02674112e-01 1.60000011e-01]
  [4.63423669e-01 2.46172473e-01 9.89436265e-03 ... 2.09036488e-02
   5.80585420e-01 8.09999943e-01]
  [1.38543904e-01 1.56719349e-02 5.86461043e-04 ... 3.39257857e-03
   1.39181942e-01 4.83793646e-01]
  ...
  [4.58064461e+00 7.45822117e-02 2.22630406e-04 ... 1.49358565e-03
   1.76204622e+00 1.31853864e-01]
  [5.92713165e+00 1.01549268e-01 2.64897913e-04 ... 1.74445310e-03
   2.32883406e+00 2.15858519e-01]
  [6.92767382e+00 1.24643743e-01 2.99515697e-04 ... 1.94842287e-03
   2.82346582e+00 2.90022254e-01]]], shape=(50, 300, 10), dtype=float32)
coxnorm :  tf.Tensor(
[[[-1.12928557e+00 -1.07866120e+00  1.34094453e+00 ... -1.48923039e+00
   -1.46297288e+00 -1.19497764e+00]
  [-7.19054937e-01 -8.01645875e-01  4.88603145e-01 ... -8.02381992e-01
   -9.84436631e-01 -7.90362477e-01]
  [-1.63032502e-01  0.00000000e+00  6.89791795e-03 ... -1.15353562e-01
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
  ...
  [ 7.91331410e-01  2.82848030e-01 -6.62079901e-02 ...  7.56768212e-02
    1.31348372e+00 -5.55337727e-01]
  [ 3.62942648e+00  5.71789861e-01 -9.80555415e-02 ...  1.46921098e-01
    3.44706607e+00  1.96308598e-01]
  [-2.60455704e+01 -1.20590663e+00 -5.96858598e-02 ...  8.99124965e-02
   -1.07716503e+01 -6.76991129e+00]]

 [[ 1.26291990e-01  8.09724852e-02 -2.35758141e-01 ...  2.37034559e-01
    2.39335880e-01  1.26506746e-01]
  [ 1.82073574e+01  8.10479259e+00 -2.68633900e+01 ...  2.43623886e+01
    3.12757339e+01  1.20329685e+01]
  [ 2.27860846e-02 -5.76828665e-04 -8.41075704e-02 ... -3.14924389e-01
   -5.45858443e-01  1.53600916e-01]
  ...
  [-8.45765781e+00 -3.25874500e-02 -2.53396958e-01 ...  4.94077355e-01
    1.36906028e-01 -9.43076134e+00]
  [-5.16309500e-01  3.31647247e-02 -8.59462023e-02 ...  1.06326245e-01
    7.70440280e-01 -1.55546510e+00]
  [ 1.88264489e+00  2.81140387e-01 -9.35972184e-02 ...  1.51024312e-01
    2.24940491e+00 -4.23506498e-01]]

 [[-3.51021881e-03  9.29604378e-03 -8.30480549e-03 ...  2.75852997e-03
    3.49582313e-03  4.20749933e-03]
  [-1.19460039e-01 -7.46591315e-02  2.09232658e-01 ... -1.11811787e-01
   -4.48986106e-02 -6.56794533e-02]
  [ 7.73615912e-02  1.39640912e-01 -5.99039733e-01 ...  3.02204281e-01
    1.21540532e-01  1.39753804e-01]
  ...
  [-0.00000000e+00  6.19232655e-02 -2.88226884e-02 ... -0.00000000e+00
   -0.00000000e+00 -1.72455922e-01]
  [-1.43807262e-01 -2.93664951e-02 -2.84313168e-02 ...  6.95512490e-03
    1.31911403e-02 -6.19950056e-01]
  [-5.72543204e-01 -3.61064710e-02 -3.36159877e-02 ...  2.38329768e-02
    1.71635970e-02 -6.77900970e-01]]

 ...

 [[-1.35804305e-03  0.00000000e+00 -0.00000000e+00 ... -7.32984021e-02
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
  [ 3.80694062e-01  4.24459547e-01 -1.02835417e-01 ...  4.95705456e-02
    1.11367142e+00  5.58833301e-01]
  [ 4.26117301e-01  3.14621657e-01  1.15071591e-02 ... -1.21318273e-01
    2.31188536e+00  8.92893672e-01]
  ...
  [-8.70169997e-02  6.87738732e-02 -2.21735947e-02 ... -2.08465792e-02
   -2.91573077e-01  3.81217501e-03]
  [ 5.48573971e-01  3.32262926e-03 -1.01672420e-02 ... -3.89767922e-02
   -2.31649205e-01 -2.24206503e-02]
  [ 7.43575245e-02  2.20210627e-02 -2.10932996e-02 ... -8.19485635e-03
   -7.10245669e-02 -3.95432487e-02]]

 [[-3.92127335e-01 -2.74757743e-01  4.89861161e-01 ... -5.16122460e-01
   -4.53032285e-01 -4.70341802e-01]
  [-1.82110667e+00 -1.75042927e+00  1.93065357e+00 ... -2.09601021e+00
   -1.60555744e+00 -1.96178496e+00]
  [-2.21494102e+00 -2.75131297e+00  1.18542504e+00 ... -2.30422640e+00
   -2.92640328e+00 -2.37486672e+00]
  ...
  [-4.95104694e+00  1.01743713e-01  7.10035488e-03 ... -1.54588342e-01
   -5.19567871e+00  7.10882246e-02]
  [-4.76147652e+00  2.87448585e-01 -8.30541085e-03 ... -1.26583263e-01
   -4.76988125e+00  3.32354397e-01]
  [-1.84991360e+00  5.35031915e-01 -3.37006189e-02 ... -5.44492975e-02
   -2.03513288e+00  6.79451108e-01]]

 [[ 1.51624024e-01  1.28273532e-01 -2.13889152e-01 ...  2.02171385e-01
    4.23870742e-01  9.69379917e-02]
  [ 4.91090089e-01  1.08586222e-01 -9.24532339e-02 ...  2.49381974e-01
    1.20175791e+00  3.18795413e-01]
  [ 6.82497621e-02 -8.44849050e-02 -3.32424268e-02 ... -2.29693111e-02
    1.43765226e-01 -3.69338304e-01]
  ...
  [-1.13121140e+00  6.44623518e-01 -4.59513478e-02 ... -3.09174340e-02
   -1.06189823e+00  7.41550148e-01]
  [-9.58280504e-01  8.23544800e-01 -5.37016653e-02 ... -2.50598919e-02
   -9.15597975e-01  1.03948617e+00]
  [-1.37292528e+00  9.15888011e-01 -5.39136417e-02 ... -3.53126153e-02
   -1.34420526e+00  1.18860805e+00]]], shape=(50, 300, 10), dtype=float32)
Z :  tf.Tensor(
[[[ 4.00928593e+00  3.95866132e+00  3.58227491e-02 ...  3.41010189e+00
    4.34297276e+00  4.07497787e+00]
  [ 1.03905499e+00  1.12164593e+00 -4.51924235e-01 ...  9.02457952e-01
    1.30443656e+00  1.11036253e+00]
  [ 2.07478195e-01  0.00000000e+00 -6.84848521e-03 ...  1.19002707e-01
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
  ...
  [-4.92860436e-01 -2.69463390e-01  6.63970262e-02 ... -7.44041428e-02
   -9.30065155e-01  6.09273612e-01]
  [-9.92372155e-01 -5.27055740e-01  9.83292460e-02 ... -1.44880831e-01
   -2.32388091e+00 -1.90607771e-01]
  [ 3.40158577e+01  1.24490762e+00  5.96998669e-02 ... -8.98667499e-02
    1.14282780e+01  8.11137772e+00]]

 [[ 8.53707969e-01  8.99027467e-01  9.04693723e-01 ...  5.40495455e-01
    7.40664124e-01  8.53493214e-01]
  [ 1.25316841e+02  8.66859589e+01  6.36312981e+01 ...  3.13919830e+01
    1.13975624e+02  1.35887054e+02]
  [ 1.67960942e-01  1.69458836e-02  1.27224952e-01 ...  4.00781810e-01
    8.04265976e-01 -8.02309960e-02]
  ...
  [ 8.94765186e+00  3.25949751e-02  2.53525764e-01 ... -4.93436426e-01
   -1.36856824e-01  9.91585159e+00]
  [ 5.55350900e-01 -3.28403413e-02  8.61506164e-02 ... -1.05421819e-01
   -7.22943068e-01  1.76578867e+00]
  [-1.33254147e+00 -2.67492950e-01  9.38301086e-02 ... -1.49337292e-01
   -1.87511349e+00  4.54916060e-01]]

 [[ 6.29468113e-02  1.18986130e-01  8.92579183e-02 ...  7.72414804e-02
    8.48637819e-02  6.46249130e-02]
  [ 6.52484417e-01  8.75198841e-01  5.10767341e-01 ...  8.31811786e-01
    6.81420445e-01  6.56740546e-01]
  [ 2.59331489e+00  3.24035883e+00  3.97903943e+00 ...  3.07779551e+00
    2.37880921e+00  2.62365413e+00]
  ...
  [ 2.39880406e-03 -5.56742772e-02  2.89395396e-02 ...  1.08112453e-03
    2.14949369e-01  2.64303327e-01]
  [ 7.91435719e-01  2.98042390e-02  2.85226610e-02 ... -6.35044696e-03
   -1.10158911e-02  9.63918567e-01]
  [ 1.38623881e+00  3.66533585e-02  3.37002985e-02 ... -2.32533701e-02
   -1.68629698e-02  1.03071463e+00]]

 ...

 [[ 1.36118464e-03  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 ...  7.56571665e-02
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
  [-2.99294680e-01 -3.08886737e-01  1.04451627e-01 ... -4.92925495e-02
   -9.33671355e-01 -3.78833294e-01]
  [-2.79817224e-01 -1.43869907e-01 -1.14447083e-02 ...  1.23193316e-01
   -1.59188533e+00 -1.72893643e-01]
  ...
  [ 1.52707115e-01 -6.16364516e-02  2.22983807e-02 ...  2.22046562e-02
    5.57268739e-01  3.29640470e-02]
  [-1.41818151e-01 -3.29589937e-03  1.02441749e-02 ...  3.97363938e-02
    2.58482307e-01  2.24055171e-01]
  [ 1.12644017e-01 -2.14095749e-02  2.11774018e-02 ...  9.03431140e-03
    1.34086102e-01  1.94440246e-01]]

 [[ 2.39212728e+00  2.27475786e+00  1.10613358e+00 ...  2.35983706e+00
    2.45303226e+00  2.47034168e+00]
  [ 5.20110607e+00  5.13042927e+00 -7.60900497e-01 ...  4.12007904e+00
    4.98555708e+00  5.34178448e+00]
  [ 4.63494110e+00  5.17131329e+00 -1.01404023e+00 ...  2.91690159e+00
    5.34640312e+00  4.79486656e+00]
  ...
  [ 1.23927393e+01 -4.28518653e-03 -6.85520656e-03 ...  1.57057136e-01
    7.98459053e+00  1.51547506e-01]
  [ 1.79844799e+01 -1.14030726e-01  8.65002070e-03 ...  1.29712835e-01
    9.21384048e+00  1.58520728e-01]
  [ 1.23724833e+01 -3.62647474e-01  3.40705775e-02 ...  5.74745536e-02
    6.26166725e+00 -2.97046185e-01]]

 [[ 8.68019462e-03  7.87069052e-02  2.55895942e-01 ... -1.60551459e-01
   -2.18522504e-01  2.23062038e-01]
  [ 4.35757250e-01  3.83758724e-01  1.12241961e-01 ... -2.07574680e-01
   -4.05870676e-02  1.30120444e+00]
  [ 2.08838046e-01  1.15828782e-01  3.44153494e-02 ...  2.97544692e-02
    1.34598657e-01  1.33692563e+00]
  ...
  [ 1.02925005e+01 -4.95459080e-01  4.63966094e-02 ...  3.39046046e-02
    4.58599091e+00 -4.77842391e-01]
  [ 1.28125439e+01 -6.20446265e-01  5.42314611e-02 ...  2.85487976e-02
    5.57326603e+00 -6.07769132e-01]
  [ 1.52282734e+01 -6.66600525e-01  5.45126759e-02 ...  3.92094627e-02
    6.99113703e+00 -6.08563542e-01]]], shape=(50, 300, 10), dtype=float32)
N :  tf.Tensor(
[[[4.09280121e-01 6.25154555e-01 4.00471878e+00 ... 5.85541010e-01
   4.47208256e-01 4.20373648e-01]
  [1.34936047e+00 2.70424366e+00 3.75102234e+01 ... 1.40959680e+00
   2.11255097e+00 1.23723638e+00]
  [3.32743907e+00 6.95078802e+00 5.68003044e+01 ... 2.18048215e+00
   7.79253483e+00 4.89925814e+00]
  ...
  [1.31312218e+01 3.08618605e-01            nan ...            inf
              inf 1.64952540e+00]
  [2.29258442e+01 3.31766039e-01            nan ...            inf
              inf 2.55500746e+00]
  [5.65075283e-18 1.16494589e-01            nan ...            inf
   0.00000000e+00 2.16516834e-02]]

 [[3.01279497e+00 3.23066592e+00 2.66553330e+00 ... 3.45391417e+00
   3.42385197e+00 2.99039698e+00]
  [8.69753424e-30 2.19426641e-19 2.27770927e-32 ... 1.57008573e-09
   5.83294553e-30 1.57146555e-30]
  [1.98644245e+00 1.59578621e-01 3.53067735e-04 ... 5.33221185e-01
   8.96145627e-02 6.53496647e+00]
  ...
  [6.65144057e-07 4.06560779e-01            nan ...            inf
              inf 1.63151638e-03]
  [2.76135278e+00 1.85385033e-01            nan ...            inf
              inf 6.67726457e-01]
  [2.56393471e+01 2.24818110e-01            nan ...            inf
              inf 1.74768591e+00]]

 [[4.19902229e+00 4.95655727e+00 4.33138084e+00 ... 4.54116726e+00
   3.66282892e+00 4.15652561e+00]
  [3.03967977e+00 3.42661023e+00 3.51902342e+00 ... 3.14248729e+00
   2.73447204e+00 3.17786717e+00]
  [1.11612952e+00 1.07797146e+00 1.23025939e-01 ... 8.13025892e-01
   1.13459349e+00 1.18541253e+00]
  ...
  [4.46164942e+00 3.01080316e-01            nan ... 1.42103520e-24
   0.00000000e+00 2.38727999e+00]
  [2.44936776e+00 2.69368589e-01            nan ...            inf
   9.51598783e+32 1.16099310e+00]
  [1.35494268e+00 2.43763462e-01            nan ...            inf
              inf 1.12819397e+00]]

 ...

 [[4.17530155e+00 4.88639832e+00 4.01824856e+00 ... 4.05120182e+00
   5.41072512e+00 4.52255154e+00]
  [6.00638533e+00 5.13792372e+00 2.24334073e+00 ... 5.08639860e+00
   2.40659981e+01 5.87329626e+00]
  [1.45305681e+01 3.02104712e+00 4.52507744e+08 ... 2.45431527e-01
   1.07969375e+06 6.84564686e+00]
  ...
  [3.67620230e+00 2.10098416e-01            nan ... 0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00 1.48366332e+00]
  [4.86196709e+00 2.08135754e-01            nan ... 0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00 1.34457958e+00]
  [4.01206636e+00 2.10035712e-01            nan ... 0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00 1.40146112e+00]]

 [[1.37217784e+00 1.66478419e+00 2.54677629e+00 ... 1.42658710e+00
   1.41912937e+00 1.23723471e+00]
  [1.05487689e-01 2.78380990e-01 8.53326321e+00 ... 2.83064008e-01
   3.09407651e-01 9.56809372e-02]
  [1.22049707e-03 6.70249909e-02 5.53372773e+04 ... 3.80475745e-02
   1.07097358e-01 3.02275177e-03]
  ...
  [1.74791035e-06 2.57256866e-01            inf ... 0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00 1.44888103e+00]
  [2.15537560e-10 3.17736596e-01            nan ... 0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00 1.65376616e+00]
  [9.68532277e-08 4.15704966e-01            nan ... 0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00 2.49313974e+00]]

 [[4.27238750e+00 3.64509273e+00 3.25757003e+00 ... 4.52268124e+00
   6.40415573e+00 4.47251177e+00]
  [3.20689917e+00 2.06197500e+00 2.16695404e+00 ... 6.46740246e+00
   8.41333008e+00 2.33353400e+00]
  [4.22908735e+00 1.10550010e+00 7.42447065e-13 ... 3.32251453e+00
   7.14087486e+00 1.96858120e+00]
  ...
  [7.62711863e-07 4.26953524e-01            nan ... 0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00 3.69047046e+00]
  [6.97009472e-09 5.00237465e-01            nan ... 0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00 4.25960112e+00]
  [6.67526798e-11 5.48933148e-01            nan ... 0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00 4.51589727e+00]]], shape=(50, 300, 10), dtype=float32)
Pr1 :  tf.Tensor(
[[1.0309292e+00 4.6992564e+00 6.6890106e+00 ...           nan
            nan           nan]
 [3.2011166e+00 1.3646084e-08 7.4845338e-01 ...           nan
            nan           nan]
 [4.3695850e+00 3.1646233e+00 1.0227087e+00 ...           nan
            nan           nan]
 ...
 [4.0963287e+00 6.0712013e+00 2.7735524e+07 ...           nan
            nan           nan]
 [1.7189162e+00 1.2319874e+00 4.4398677e+03 ...           inf
            nan           nan]
 [4.4072876e+00 4.2843428e+00 2.0467470e+00 ...           nan
            nan           nan]], shape=(50, 300), dtype=float32)
Pr :  tf.Tensor(
[[1.0309292e+00 4.6992564e+00 6.6890106e+00 ...           nan
            nan           nan]
 [3.2011166e+00 1.3646084e-08 7.4845338e-01 ...           nan
            nan           nan]
 [4.3695850e+00 3.1646233e+00 1.0227087e+00 ...           nan
            nan           nan]
 ...
 [4.0963287e+00 6.0712013e+00 2.7735524e+07 ...           nan
            nan           nan]
 [1.7189162e+00 1.2319874e+00 4.4398677e+03 ...           inf
            nan           nan]
 [4.4072876e+00 4.2843428e+00 2.0467470e+00 ...           nan
            nan           nan]], shape=(50, 300), dtype=float32)
loss1 :  tf.Tensor(
[[ -0.03046065  -1.5474043   -1.900466   ...          nan          nan
           nan]
 [ -1.1634997   15.834004     0.2897462  ...          nan          nan
           nan]
 [ -1.474668    -1.152034    -0.02245477 ...          nan          nan
           nan]
 ...
 [ -1.4100912   -1.8035564  -17.138226   ...          nan          nan
           nan]
 [ -0.54169405  -0.2086287   -8.39838    ...         -inf          nan
           nan]
 [ -1.4832594   -1.4549671   -0.7162518  ...          nan          nan
           nan]], shape=(50, 300), dtype=float32)
bernouilli2 :  tf.Tensor(
[[[0.6423321 ]
  [0.7828194 ]
  [0.9196569 ]
  ...
  [0.9998647 ]
  [0.9998626 ]
  [0.9998597 ]]

 [[0.5782246 ]
  [0.6845753 ]
  [0.94125485]
  ...
  [0.9998617 ]
  [0.9997705 ]
  [0.9998255 ]]

 [[0.5       ]
  [0.5       ]
  [0.5       ]
  ...
  [0.99985975]
  [0.9998565 ]
  [0.9998628 ]]

 ...

 [[0.6627238 ]
  [0.8552569 ]
  [0.9674034 ]
  ...
  [0.9998675 ]
  [0.9998696 ]
  [0.9998716 ]]

 [[0.557677  ]
  [0.65871966]
  [0.80233204]
  ...
  [0.9998928 ]
  [0.99989057]
  [0.99988616]]

 [[0.67558116]
  [0.85534775]
  [0.9619842 ]
  ...
  [0.99986994]
  [0.9998687 ]
  [0.99986684]]], shape=(50, 300, 1), dtype=float32)
loss2 :  tf.Tensor(
[[[4.4264966e-01]
  [2.4485312e-01]
  [8.3754517e-02]
  ...
  [1.3519247e-04]
  [1.3727891e-04]
  [1.4019995e-04]]

 [[5.4779267e-01]
  [3.7895644e-01]
  [6.0541213e-02]
  ...
  [1.3817311e-04]
  [2.2938498e-04]
  [1.7441840e-04]]

 [[6.9314694e-01]
  [6.9314694e-01]
  [6.9314694e-01]
  ...
  [1.4014034e-04]
  [1.4341906e-04]
  [1.3710008e-04]]

 ...

 [[4.1139680e-01]
  [1.5635324e-01]
  [3.3139568e-02]
  ...
  [1.3239068e-04]
  [1.3030424e-04]
  [1.2827742e-04]]

 [[5.8397520e-01]
  [4.1745704e-01]
  [2.2023259e-01]
  ...
  [1.0711528e-04]
  [1.0932089e-04]
  [1.1373213e-04]]

 [[3.9218181e-01]
  [1.5624702e-01]
  [3.8757112e-02]
  ...
  [1.2994657e-04]
  [1.3119842e-04]
  [1.3304641e-04]]], shape=(50, 300, 1), dtype=float32)
loss_val :  None
```

Comment: Removing the `nan` or `inf` from the data set is a pre-processing method. Your model must not deal with them, at least from current development.

Comment: The dataset doesn't contain nan or inf they are produced as a result of the calculation